# How to implement DUKPT encryption & decryption in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android

I need to implement DUKPT encryption & decryption in Java/Android.

I have studied the reference and understand somewhat. I searched any any tutorial with sample code in Java to implement but I have not got any sample.

Can anybody know how to implement this in Java.

Any help or suggestion will be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For decryption, you can see this project I make with a friend :
https://github.com/jewom/android-magtek-jack-audio-reader

Check this Class :

```
package com.magtek.mobile.android.mtscrademo;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;

/**
 * The Dukpt class acts a name-space for the Derived
 * Unique Key-Per-Transaction (Dukpt) standard using the
 * Data Encryption Standard, DES, (often referred to in practice as
 * "DEA", for Data Encryption Algorithm).
 *
 *  The functions provided attempt to aid a user in performing
 * encryption, decryption, and possibly more complex operations
 * using these.
 *
 *  There is also a set of conversion methods to hopefully make
 * the class even easier to interface with.  Many of these involve
 * the BitSet wrapper of java.util.BitSet which was designed to have
 * a proper "length()" function as Java's BitSet does not have a method
 * that returns the constructed length of the BitSet, only its actual
 * size in memory and its "logical" size (1 + the index of the left-most 1).
 *
 *  To further augment to the security of Dukpt, two "oblivate()" methods are
 * included, one for the extended BitSet and one for byte arrays.  These
 * overwrite their respective arguments with random data as supplied by
 * java.secruty.SecureRandom to ensure that their randomness is
 * cryptographically strong.  The default number of overwrites is specified by
 * the static constant NUM_OVERWRITES but the user can supply a different number
 * should they desire the option.
 *
 * @author Antoine Averlant
 * @author Antoine Averlant
 */
public final class Dukpt {
    public static final int NUM_OVERWRITES = 3;

    /**
     * Computes a DUKPT (Derived Unique Key-Per-Transaction).
     *
     *  This is derived from the Base Derivation Key, which should
     * have been injected into the device and should remain secret,
     * and the Key Serial Number which is a concatenation of the
     * device's serial number and its encryption (or transaction)
     * counter.
     *
     * see getIpek
     * @param baseDerivationKey The Base Derivation Key
     * @param keySerialNumber The Key Serial Number
     * @return A unique key for this set of data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] computeKey(byte[] baseDerivationKey, byte[] keySerialNumber) throws Exception {
        BitSet ksn = toBitSet(keySerialNumber);
        BitSet bdk = toBitSet(baseDerivationKey);
        BitSet ipek = getIpek(bdk, ksn);

        // convert key for returning
        BitSet key = _getCurrentKey(ipek, ksn);
        byte[] rkey = toByteArray(key);

        // secure memory
        obliviate(ksn);
        obliviate(bdk);
        obliviate(ipek);
        obliviate(key);

        return rkey;
    }

    /**
     * Computes the Initial PIN Encryption Key (Sometimes referred to as
     * the Initial PIN Entry Device Key).
     *
     *  Within the function, the transaction counter is removed.
     * This is because the IPEK should be seen as the Dukpt
     * (Derived Unique Key-Per-Transaction) corresponding to a brand
     * new transaction counter (assuming it starts at 0).
     *
     *  Due to the process under which one key is derived from a subset of
     * those before it, the IPEK can be used to quickly calculate the
     * DUKPT for any Key Serial Number, or more specifically, any
     * encryption count.
     *
     *  This algorithm was found in Annex A, section 6 on page 69
     * of the ANSI X9.24-1:2009 document.
     *
     * @param key The Base Derivation Key.
     * @param ksn The Key Serial Number.
     * @return The Initial PIN Encryption Key
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static BitSet getIpek(BitSet key, BitSet ksn) throws Exception {
        byte[][] ipek = new byte[2][];
        BitSet keyRegister = key.get(0, key.length());
        BitSet data = ksn.get(0, ksn.length());
        data.clear(59, 80);

        ipek[0] = encryptTripleDes(toByteArray(keyRegister), toByteArray(data.get(0, 64)));

        keyRegister.xor(toBitSet(toByteArray("C0C0C0C000000000C0C0C0C000000000")));
        ipek[1] = encryptTripleDes(toByteArray(keyRegister), toByteArray(data.get(0, 64)));

        byte[] bipek = concat(ipek[0], ipek[1]);
        BitSet bsipek = toBitSet(bipek);

        // secure memory
        obliviate(ipek[0]);
        obliviate(ipek[1]);
        obliviate(bipek);
        obliviate(keyRegister);
        obliviate(data);

        return bsipek;
    }

    /**
     * Computes a Dukpt (Derived Unique Key-Per-Transaction) given an IPEK
     * and Key Serial Number.
     *
     *  Here, a non-reversible operation is used to find one key from
     * another.  This is where the transaction counter comes in.  In order
     * to have the desired number of possible unique keys (over 1 million)
     * for a given device, a transaction counter size of 20 bits would
     * suffice.  However, by adding an extra bit and a constraint (that
     * keys must have AT MOST 9* bits set) the same number of values can be
     * achieved while allowing a user to calculate the key in at most 9
     * steps.
     *
     * *    We have reason to believe that is actually 10 bits (as the
     * sum of the 21 choose i for i from 0 to 9 is only around 700,000 while
     * taking i from 0 to 10 yields exactly 2^20 (just over 1,000,000) values)
     * but regardless of the truth, our algorithm is not dependent upon this
     * figure and will work no matter how it is implemented in the encrypting
     * device or application.
     *
     *  This algorithm was found in Annex A, section 3 on pages 50-54
     * of the ANSI X9.24-1:2009 document.
     *
     * @param ipek The Initial PIN Encryption Key.
     * @param ksn The Key Serial Number.
     * @return The Dukpt that corresponds to this combination of values.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static BitSet _getCurrentKey(BitSet ipek, BitSet ksn) throws Exception {
        BitSet key = ipek.get(0, ipek.length());
        BitSet counter = ksn.get(0, ksn.length());
        counter.clear(59, ksn.length());

        for (int i = 59; i < ksn.length(); i++) {
            if (ksn.get(i)) {
                counter.set(i);
                BitSet tmp = _nonReversibleKeyGenerationProcess(key, counter.get(16, 80));
                // secure memory
                obliviate(key);
                key = tmp;
            }
        }
        key.xor(toBitSet(toByteArray("00000000000000FF00000000000000FF"))); // data encryption variant (To PIN)
        // key.xor(toBitSet(toByteArray("F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0"))); // data encryption variant
        // key.xor(toBitSet(toByteArray("3C3C3C3C3C3C3C3C3C3C3C3C3C3C3C3C"))); // data encryption variant

        // secure memory
        obliviate(counter);

        return key;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new key from a previous key and the right 64 bits of the
     * Key Serial Number for the desired transaction.
     *
     *  This algorithm was found in Annex A, section 2 on page 50
     * of the ANSI X9.24-1:2009 document.
     *
     * @param p_key The previous key to be used for derivation.
     * @param data The data to encrypt it with, usually the right 64 bits of the transaction counter.
     * @return A key that cannot be traced back to p_key.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static BitSet _nonReversibleKeyGenerationProcess(BitSet p_key, BitSet data) throws Exception {
        BitSet keyreg = p_key.get(0, p_key.length());
        BitSet reg1 = data.get(0, data.length());
        // step 1: Crypto Register-1 XORed with the right half of the Key Register goes to Crypto Register-2.
        BitSet reg2 = reg1.get(0, 64); // reg2 is being used like a temp here
        reg2.xor(keyreg.get(64, 128));   // and here, too, kind of
        // step 2: Crypto Register-2 DEA-encrypted using, as the key, the left half of the Key Register goes to Crypto Register-2
        reg2 = toBitSet(encryptDes(toByteArray(keyreg.get(0, 64)), toByteArray(reg2)));
        // step 3: Crypto Register-2 XORed with the right half of the Key Register goes to Crypto Register-2
        reg2.xor(keyreg.get(64, 128));
        // done messing with reg2

        // step 4: XOR the Key Register with hexadecimal C0C0 C0C0 0000 0000 C0C0 C0C0 0000 0000
        keyreg.xor(toBitSet(toByteArray("C0C0C0C000000000C0C0C0C000000000")));
        // step 5: Crypto Register-1 XORed with the right half of the Key Register goes to Crypto Register-1
        reg1.xor(keyreg.get(64, 128));
        // step 6: Crypto Register-1 DEA-encrypted using, as the key, the left half of the Key Register goes to Crypto Register-1
        reg1 = toBitSet(encryptDes(toByteArray(keyreg.get(0, 64)), toByteArray(reg1)));
        // step 7: Crypto Register-1 XORed with the right half of the Key Register goes to Crypto Register-1
        reg1.xor(keyreg.get(64, 128));
        // done

        byte[] reg1b = toByteArray(reg1), reg2b = toByteArray(reg2);
        byte[] key = concat(reg1b, reg2b);
        BitSet rkey = toBitSet(key);

        // secure memory
        obliviate(reg1);
        obliviate(reg2);
        obliviate(reg1b);
        obliviate(reg2b);
        obliviate(key);
        obliviate(keyreg);

        return rkey;
    }

    /**
     * Performs Single DES Encryption.
     *
     * @param key The key for encryption.
     * @param data The data to encrypt.
     * @param padding When true, PKCS5 Padding will be used.  This is most likely not desirable.
     * @return The encrypted.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] encryptDes(byte[] key, byte[] data, boolean padding) throws Exception {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        SecretKey encryptKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(key));
        Cipher encryptor;
        if (padding)
            encryptor = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        else
            encryptor = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding");
        encryptor.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptKey, iv);
        return encryptor.doFinal(data);
    }

    /**
     * Performs Single DES Decryption.
     *
     * @param key The key for decryption.
     * @param data The data to decrypt.
     * @param padding When true, PKCS5 Padding will be assumed.  This is most likely not desirable.
     * @return The decrypted data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] decryptDes(byte[] key, byte[] data, boolean padding) throws Exception {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        SecretKey decryptKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(key));
        Cipher decryptor;
        if (padding)
            decryptor = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        else
            decryptor = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding");
        decryptor.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, decryptKey, iv);
        return decryptor.doFinal(data);
    }

    /**
     * Performs Single DEA Encryption without padding.
     *
     * @param key The key for encryption.
     * @param data The data to encrypt.
     * @return The encrypted data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] encryptDes(byte[] key, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        return encryptDes(key, data, false);
    }

    /**
     * Performs Single DES Decryption assuming no padding was used.
     *
     * @param key The key for decryption.
     * @param data The data to decrypt.
     * @return The decrypted data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] decryptDes(byte[] key, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        return decryptDes(key, data, false);
    }

    /**
     * Performs Triple DES Encryption.
     *
     * @param key The key for encryption.
     * @param data The data to encrypt.
     * @param padding When true, PKCS5 Padding will be used.  This is most likely not desirable.
     * @return The encrypted data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] encryptTripleDes(byte[] key, byte[] data, boolean padding) throws Exception {
        BitSet bskey = toBitSet(key);
        BitSet k1, k2, k3;
        if (bskey.length() == 64) {
            // single length
            k1 = bskey.get(0, 64);
            k2 = k1;
            k3 = k1;
        } else if (bskey.length() == 128) {
            // double length
            k1 = bskey.get(0, 64);
            k2 = bskey.get(64, 128);
            k3 = k1;
        } else {
            // triple length
            if (bskey.length() != 192) {
                throw new InvalidParameterException("Key is not 8/16/24 bytes long.");
            }
            k1 = bskey.get(0, 64);
            k2 = bskey.get(64, 128);
            k3 = bskey.get(128, 192);
        }
        byte[] kb1 = toByteArray(k1), kb2 = toByteArray(k2), kb3 = toByteArray(k3);
        byte[] key16 = concat(kb1, kb2);
        byte[] key24 = concat(key16, kb3);

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        SecretKey encryptKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(key24));
        Cipher encryptor;
        if (padding)
            encryptor = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        else
            encryptor = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
        encryptor.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptKey, iv);
        byte[] bytes = encryptor.doFinal(data);

        // secure memory
        obliviate(k1);
        obliviate(k2);
        obliviate(k3);
        obliviate(kb1);
        obliviate(kb2);
        obliviate(kb3);
        obliviate(key16);
        obliviate(key24);
        obliviate(bskey);

        return bytes;
    }

    /**
     * Performs Triple DES Decryption.
     *
     * @param key The key for decryption.
     * @param data The data to decrypt.
     * @param padding When true, PKCS5 Padding will be assumed.  This is most likely not desirable.
     * @return The decrypted data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] decryptTripleDes(byte[] key, byte[] data, boolean padding) throws Exception {
        BitSet bskey = toBitSet(key);
        BitSet k1, k2, k3;
        if (bskey.length() == 64) {
            // single length
            k1 = bskey.get(0, 64);
            k2 = k1;
            k3 = k1;
        } else if (bskey.length() == 128) {
            // double length
            k1 = bskey.get(0, 64);
            k2 = bskey.get(64, 128);
            k3 = k1;
        } else {
            // triple length
            if (bskey.length() != 192) {
                throw new InvalidParameterException("Key is not 8/16/24 bytes long.");
            }
            k1 = bskey.get(0, 64);
            k2 = bskey.get(64, 128);
            k3 = bskey.get(128, 192);
        }
        byte[] kb1 = toByteArray(k1), kb2 = toByteArray(k2), kb3 = toByteArray(k3);
        byte[] key16 = concat(kb1, kb2);
        byte[] key24 = concat(key16, kb3);

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        SecretKey encryptKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(key24));
        Cipher decryptor;
        if (padding)
            decryptor = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        else
            decryptor = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
        decryptor.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, encryptKey, iv);
        byte[] bytes = decryptor.doFinal(data);

        // secure memory
        obliviate(k1);
        obliviate(k2);
        obliviate(k3);
        obliviate(kb1);
        obliviate(kb2);
        obliviate(kb3);
        obliviate(key16);
        obliviate(key24);
        obliviate(bskey);

        return bytes;
    }

    /**
     * Performs Single DEA Encryption without padding.
     *
     * @param key The key for encryption.
     * @param data The data to encrypt.
     * @return The encrypted data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] encryptTripleDes(byte[] key, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        return encryptTripleDes(key, data, false);
    }

    /**
     * Performs Triple DEA Decryption without padding.
     *
     * @param key The key for decryption.
     * @param data The data to decrypt.
     * @return The decrypted data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] decryptTripleDes(byte[] key, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        return decryptTripleDes(key, data, false);
    }

    /**
     * Performs Single AES Encryption.
     *
     * This is supplied for use generic encryption and decryption purposes, but is not a part of the Dukpt algorithm.
     *
     * @param key The key for encryption.
     * @param data The data to encrypt.
     * @param padding When true, PKCS5 Padding will be used.  This is most likely not desirable.
     * @return The encrypted.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] encryptAes(byte[] key, byte[] data, boolean padding) throws Exception {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
        SecretKeySpec encryptKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        Cipher encryptor;
        if (padding)
            encryptor = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        else
            encryptor = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        encryptor.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptKey, iv);
        return encryptor.doFinal(data);
    }

    /**
     * Performs Single AES Decryption.
     *
     * This is supplied for use generic encryption and decryption purposes, but is not a part of the Dukpt algorithm.
     *
     * @param key The key for decryption.
     * @param data The data to decrypt.
     * @param padding When true, PKCS5 Padding will be assumed.  This is most likely not desirable.
     * @return The decrypted data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] decryptAes(byte[] key, byte[] data, boolean padding) throws Exception {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
        SecretKeySpec decryptKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        Cipher decryptor;
        if (padding)
            decryptor = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        else
            decryptor = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        decryptor.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, decryptKey, iv);
        return decryptor.doFinal(data);
    }

    /**
     * Performs Single AES Encryption without padding.
     *
     *  This is supplied for use generic encryption and decryption purposes, but is not a part of the Dukpt algorithm.
     *
     * @param key The key for encryption.
     * @param data The data to encrypt.
     * @return The encrypted data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] encryptAes(byte[] key, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        return encryptAes(key, data, false);
    }

    /**
     * Performs Triple AES Decryption without padding.
     *
     *  This is supplied for use generic encryption and decryption purposes, but is not a part of the Dukpt algorithm.
     *
     * @param key The key for decryption.
     * @param data The data to decrypt.
     * @return The decrypted data.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static byte[] decryptAes(byte[] key, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        return decryptAes(key, data, false);
    }

    /** Converts a byte into an extended BitSet. */
    public static BitSet toBitSet(byte b) {
        BitSet bs = new BitSet(8);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if ((b & (1L << i)) > 0) {
                bs.set(7 - i);
            }
        }
        return bs;
    }

    /** Converts a byte array to an extended BitSet. */
    public static BitSet toBitSet(byte[] b) {
        BitSet bs = new BitSet(8 * b.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if ((b[i] & (1L << j)) > 0) {
                    bs.set(8 * i + (7 - j));
                }
            }
        }
        return bs;
    }

    /**
     * Converts an extended BitSet into a byte.
     *
     * Requires that the BitSet be exactly 8 bits long.
     */
    public static byte toByte(BitSet b) {
        byte value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            if (b.get(i))
                value = (byte) (value | (1L << 7 - i));
        }
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a BitSet into a byte array.
     *
     * Pads to the left with zeroes.
     */
    public static byte[] toByteArray(BitSet b) {
        int size = (int) Math.ceil(b.length() / 8.0d);
        byte[] value = new byte[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            value[i] = toByte(b.get(i * 8, Math.min(b.length(), (i + 1) * 8)));
        }
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a hexadecimal String into a byte array (Big-Endian).
     * @param s A representation of a hexadecimal number without any leading qualifiers such as "0x" or "x".
     */
    public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a byte array into a hexadecimal string (Big-Endian).
     * @return A representation of a hexadecimal number without any leading qualifiers such as "0x" or "x".
     */
    public static String toHex(byte[] bytes) {
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, bytes);
        return String.format("%0" + (bytes.length << 1) + "X", bi);
    }

    /**
     * Concatenates two byte arrays.
     * @return The array a concatenated with b.  So if r is the returned array, r[0] = a[0] and r[a.length] = b[0].
     */
    public static byte[] concat(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
        byte[] c = new byte[a.length + b.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            c[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            c[a.length + i] = b[i];
        }
        return c;
    }
    /** Overwrites the extended BitSet NUM_OVERWRITES times with random data for security purposes. */
    public static void obliviate(BitSet b) {
        obliviate(b, NUM_OVERWRITES);
    }

    /** Overwrites the byte array NUM_OVERWRITES times with random data for security purposes. */
    public static void obliviate(byte[] b) {
        obliviate(b, NUM_OVERWRITES);
    }

    /** Overwrites the extended BitSet with random data for security purposes. */
    public static void obliviate(BitSet b, int n) {
        java.security.SecureRandom r = new java.security.SecureRandom();
        for (int i=0; i<NUM_OVERWRITES; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<b.length(); j++) {
                b.set(j, r.nextBoolean());
            }
        }
    }

    /** Overwrites the byte array with random data for security purposes. */
    public static void obliviate(byte[] b, int n) {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            b[i] = 0x00;
            b[i] = 0x01;
        }

        java.security.SecureRandom r = new java.security.SecureRandom();
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            r.nextBytes(b);
        }
    }
```